# prevent unchecking radio button by clicking on it in matlab

Tags: matlab, radio-button, matlab-guide

I created GUI using GUIDE and placed to radio buttons in one button-group panel. This conveniently takes care of unchecking one radio button whenever the other one is clicked. Now what's freaking me out is I can actually uncheck a checked radio button by clicking on it a second time, leaving BOTH radio buttons unchecked. It works with either of them. The only thing I want is the standard behavior, is that asking so much....?

I'm using Matlab 7.0, unfortunately this is all I've got.

Answer (score 2):

I have 7.0 on one of my computers and r2011a on another and this non-standard behavior seems to be something that they fixed somewhere in between. Since MATLAB 7.0 is all you have, here is an easy way to fix it:

At the top of all radio button callbacks add:

```
if ~get(hObject,'Value')
    set(hObject,'Value',1)
end
```

That should fix the problem.